# Karate DSL using datagenerator by creating JSON object is returning null

Tags: scala, karate

I am trying to build a dynamic JSON object for which I am using data generator in which I am putting the data for JSON object and calling that data generator in .feature file.

The URL request is not fetching the data from the data generator and is showing as null. What is possible reason for it?

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;

public class DataGenerator {
    public static JSONObject getRandomWF(){
        String workflowId = "hello"; 
        String name = "bye";
        String description = "descc"; 
        String category = null;
        Boolean setnotify = false;
        json.put("workflowId", workflowId);
        json.put("name", name);
        json.put("description", description);
        json.put("setnotify", setnotify);
        return json;
      }
}
```

.feature file is below:

```
Given path '/workflow/create'
* header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
* def dataGenerator = Java.type('DataGenerator')
* def articleRequestBody = read('classpath:examples/users/createworkflow.json')
* set articleRequestBody.workflowId = dataGenerator.getRandomWF().workflowId
* set articleRequestBody.name = dataGenerator.getRandomWF().name
* set articleRequestBody.description = dataGenerator.getRandomWF().description
* set articleRequestBody.setnotify = dataGenerator.getRandomWF().setnotify
And request articleRequestBody
When method Post
Then status 200
```

Below is createworkflow.json:

```
{
workflowId : "id workflow"
name : "name workflow"
description : "Desc workflow"
setnotify : true
}
```

Any help in getting to know why I am getting null for each key (workflowId,name,description,setnotify) will be appreciative.

Comment: JSON requires quotes around key names and commas between entries in an object. That file is not valid JSON. Consider plugging it into a JSON lint tool to see the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

Don't use the `JSONObject` return type, whatever that is, just use a normal `Map`. Or you can return a string and do a type-conversion in Karate: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion